# How to reference multi fields when adding a document to elasticsearch

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I created an index in my Elasticsearch server and I'm using .Net client NEST to connect to it. Some of the index properties have multiple fields and I want to fill just the correct field.

I created the class 'document' to this mappaing. but I do not know how to access fields of property.

this is the mapping I have (summarized):

```
"mappings": {
      "document": {
        "properties": {

          "baseUniqueID": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "description": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "en": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "english"
              },
              "fa": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "nofapersian"
              },
              "fr": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "french"
              }
            }
          },
          "documentDate": {
            "type": "date"
          },
          "documentType_Id": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "id": {
            "type": "long"
          }

        }
      }
    }
```

and the document class:

```cs
public class Document : BaseInt32KeyEntity
    {
        public string BaseUniqueID{ get; set; }

        public int? Weight { get; set; }

        public DateTime DocumentDate { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        public int DocumentType_Id { get; set; }
    }
}
```

How can I make an object of Document to fill just the field I want (here in this example description.en) and then use IndexDocument to add it to Elasticsearch? something like this:

```cs
Document doc = new Document();
doc.Description.en = "This is some description";
ElasticClient.IndexDocument(doc);
```

Comment: I see what you mean. Once I can have a good answer for your question I will post it here. I deleted my previous answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update an individual field with the Update API

```
var client = new ElasticClient();

var documentId = 1;

var partial = new 
{
    Description = "This is some description"
};

var updateResponse = client.Update<Document, object>(documentId, u => u
    .Index("your_index")
    .Doc(partial)
);
```

The `.Index()` is only needed if you haven't set up an index convention for the `Document` type. The document to update is modelled with a partial document because using `Document` would result in sending default values for value types like the `DocumentDate` and `DocumentType_Id` properties.

> doc.Description.en = "This is some description";

It's not possible to do this as this is not how [multi-fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/multi-fields.html) work. With multi-fields, a single document field input can be analyzed in numerous different ways to serve different search needs. In your example, `Description` property value will be analyzed 4 different ways:

1. by the standard analyzer with the base `text` mapping
2. by the english analyzer with the `.en` multi-field mapping
3. by the nofapersian analyzer with the `.fa` multi-field mapping
4. by the french analyzer with the `.fr` multi-field mapping

The results of analysis will be indexed into the inverted index to allow you to search and query on them, but the original JSON document sent to Elasticsearch will only contain the one `"description"` field, which is what you will get back when you retrieve the `_source` for the document (if the `_source` is stored, which by default it is).

If you wanted to model these as separate fields on the document, the you could introduce a `Description` type that has the necessary properties

```
public class Description
{
    public string Standard { get;set; }
    public string English { get;set; }
    public string NoFaPersian{ get;set; }
    public string French{ get;set; }
}
```

and then index it as an `object` type mapping, configuring the analyzer for each

```
public class Document
{
    public string BaseUniqueID { get; set; }
    public int? Weight { get; set; }
    public DateTime DocumentDate { get; set; }
    public Description Description { get; set; }
    public int DocumentType_Id { get; set; }
}

var indexResponse = client.CreateIndex("your_index", c => c
    .Mappings(m => m
        .Map<Document>(mm => mm
            .AutoMap()
            .Properties(p => p
                .Object<Description>(o => o
                    .Name(n => n.Description)
                    .AutoMap()
                    .Properties(pp => pp
                        .Text(t => t.Name(n => n.Standard).Analyzer("standard"))
                        .Text(t => t.Name(n => n.English).Analyzer("english"))
                        .Text(t => t.Name(n => n.NoFaPersian).Analyzer("nofapersian"))
                        .Text(t => t.Name(n => n.French).Analyzer("french"))
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )       
);
```

which produces the following create index request

```
PUT http://localhost:9200/your_index?pretty=true 
{
  "mappings": {
    "document": {
      "properties": {
        "baseUniqueID": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "weight": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "documentDate": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "description": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "standard": {
              "type": "text",
              "analyzer": "standard"
            },
            "english": {
              "type": "text",
              "analyzer": "english"
            },
            "noFaPersian": {
              "type": "text",
              "analyzer": "nofapersian"
            },
            "french": {
              "type": "text",
              "analyzer": "french"
            }
          }
        },
        "documentType_Id": {
          "type": "integer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```